# dnx test on Travis with mono hangs

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, travis-ci, xunit, dnx

I'm trying to run my ASP.NET 5.0 (beta 8) tests which use xunit on Travis CI using `language: CSharp` as the build environment.

The project builds fine, and after installing `dnvm` I run the tests with `dnx test`.

However, whether the tests pass or fail, I get the following message after a while:

```
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

I think this is happening because the `dnx test` command doesn't pass control back to the Travis console when the tests have completed. Travis thinks it is still running, but is not producing any output.

I think this is related to https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/489 and this bug in Mono: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28793 but that thread says it was fixed in May 2015, and I'm running on the latest version of Mono (4.0.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be caused by a known bug. Try running the tests without parallelization and see if that helps:

```
dnx test -parallel none
```

You should be able to reproduce the issue locally too.